# RDLC-Report and CultureInfo on Datetime-Format

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc

I'm using the Report System from Visual Studio (not Crystal Reports but RDLC). It works fine, but my problem is, that when setting the "Format code" on a Date-Field to "D" it formats it to an English Date (Wednesday, June 24, 2009) instead using my CultueInfo (German) and I can't find out how to pass a Culture-Info to the Report or the Date-Format.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't set the culture on the report, try creating a property on your class that does the conversion and returns it as a string.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

    public string FormattedDate
    {
       get { return Date.ToString("D", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")); }
    }
}
```

From your report you can access it as "=Fields!FormattedDate.Value".

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was answered a while ago but I needed to get a report to use the current UI culture (rather than a hard coded culture) when formatting dates in an RDLC report.

For the current UI culture you need to set the Report's Language property to `=User!Language`. Hope this helps anyone who comes up against the same problem.

Answer (score -3):

```
=Format(Fields!FormattedDate.Value).("dd/MM/yyyy")
```